# Where can I set cognos analytics 11 report cache on/off

Tags: cognos-11

Where can I set cognos analytics 11  report  cache on/off  ?

I know how to set cache in dashboard and  story.

please help me this problem.

Answer (score 1):

In the Properties section against a specific query, change the 'Use Local Cache' property. Set the property to ‘No’ if you want to always execute the query. Set the property to 'Yes' if you want to use cached results.

[image]

Comment: Thanks.  Is  the  "Use local  cache = yes"  depend on the  data module  cache policy ?

Comment: No it is localized to the specific query, so if the query is runned against the data module it will cache the result no matter if the data module has a Data cache policy or not. The Data cache policy is between the data module and the data server.

Comment: The Data cache in the Data Module enchances the performance between the Data Module and the database whereas the Local cache enchances the performance between a specific query inside a report and the Data Module, Package etc.

Comment: OK  I got your point. I just want to fig it out the behavior of  report  and cache. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5JmKa.png)

I have a report  use  a  data module which  set  the  "data cache = 40 sec"， the content of report  will  be changed  after 40 secs  by  refreshing  a  browser.

I set the report query "use local cache =yes" ，but  If I change the database content ，the report content will be changed after 40 secs by refreshing a browser.